# How to set Sublime Text as default text editor?

Tags: fedora, gnome, mate-desktop

How to set Sublime Text as default text editor? The only option I see is Pluma.

I'm using Mate Desktop on Fedora 19.

[image]

Edit: The Sublime Text executable (installed by hand, not a package) is at `/home/matt/sublime_text_3/sublime_text`.

Comment: I imagine that clicking on the drop down menu does not show any more options right?

Comment: @terdon Pluma's the only option in the drop down

Comment: Sorry, just wanted to make sure, you never know :).

Answer (score 4):

The default file associations are set in either `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` (global) or one of `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` or `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`.

For example, this is what I have on my system:

```
$ grep -e '\[\|plain' .local/share/applications/mimeapps.list 
[Default Applications]
text/plain=pluma.desktop;
[Added Associations]
text/plain=emacs.desktop;pluma.desktop;
```

Changing the `[Added Associations]` line to

```
text/plain=sublime_text.desktop;emacs.desktop;pluma.desktop;
```

made sublime my default editor. Make sure that `sublime_text` correctly launches sublime if you run it from a terminal and that you have a `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/`:

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sublime
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=sublime_text %U
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=/usr/share/icons/mate/48x48/apps/sublime_text.png
Categories=GTK;Utility;TextEditor;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `gsettings` command along with `list-recursively` parameters such as:

```
gsettings list-recursively |egrep -i editor
```

Then apply with set command with the given key you retrived.

enjoy with :

```
gsettings list-recursively
```

Answer (score 0):

Bumping this. @PersianGulf's suggestion led me to write this, and I think it might help people who are looking for this info (and you just replace "pluma" in `app=pluma` for whatever you're looking for:

`app=pluma; gsettings list-recursively | grep -i $app | cat -n | grep -E $app`

HOWEVER, I wasn't able to get Sublime to default for all unknown text files. `sudo update-alternatives ...` isn't working for me. But I'll update if I figure it out.